# How to pass username and password for a webserivce using jquery ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services

I have a web service; in order to access it I need to use credentials. I want to invoke the web service using a **jQuery AJAX call** in another project. So how to pass username and password for that web service using that method?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the doc for [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Also this has many extra parameters. Follow the doc when you need anything extra.

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url:   'https://webservice url',
     data: ({ username: value, password: value; }) //use parameters as such defined in webservice
     success: function(data){

       }
})
```

Comment: And be sure to use HTTPS as Chris Stringfellow recommended already in his comment. Without it, your passwords are not secure.

Comment: @jeffszusz As per `jquery` doc they said `The ajax() method is used to perform an AJAX (asynchronous HTTP) request.` How to make it as `https` ?

Comment: just use https:// in the url instead of http:// and make sure your web service supports SSL

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'url',
    dataType: 'json',
    //whatever you need
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth(user, password));
    },
    success: function () {});
});

function make_base_auth(user, password) {
    var tok = user + ':' + password;
    var hash = btoa(tok);
    return 'Basic ' + hash;
}
```